# Use Visual Studio AppCenter within a ASP.NET core web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-app-center

I wanted to use the Visual Studio AppCenter in my ASP.NET core web service but it seems like it is not supported.
When calling `AppCenter.Start("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));` I get a log at runtime in the output console that says:

> "[AppCenter] ASSERT: Cannot use App Center on this target. If you are on Android or iOS or UWP, you must add the NuGet packages in the Android and iOS and UWP/WPF/WinForms projects as well. Other targets are not yet supported."

I understand that it is not supported, but isn't there a way to use it? Xamarin uses .net core as well, so technically one should somehow be able to use it in a basic .net core application right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET is not supported by the App Center. The list of supported by App Center platforms is here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/general/platform-service-matrix. Xamarin SDK uses a wrapper for Android and iOS SDK, for UWP it uses the specific c# implementation.

Comment: How about doing an own/self-implemented wrapper for Aspnet core? Is it not allowed by license terms?